# Firefox 3.5 does not allow creating OBJECT tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Firefox 3.5 does not allow creating java OBJECT tag with Javascript (document.write)?

this technique works nicely with *all* other browsers and older firefoxes.

is it a new security limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested both javascript creation of object tag and just a plain object tag for java. It seems that there is a bug in 3.5 beta 4 that it doesn't show the plugin info message for object tags.

It's got nothing to do with the javascript.

Comment: btw the applet tag still gave the normal info bar